# Can I upload a fil to an external server using Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have my Multer middleware like this:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

I'm not using the destination attribute because I was using cloudinary for development, but my PM asked me if I could use our own file server.

My idea is to do something like:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'http://fileserver/catalog')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

But it tries to open like a normal path (C:/Users/User/...)
Is this approach allowed or even possible? If it is, how can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use multer with FTP to solve your problem, using external server, you pass it via ftp

```js
var multer = require('multer')
var FTPStorage = require('multer-ftp')

var upload = multer({
  storage: new FTPStorage({
    basepath: '/remote/path',
    ftp: {
      host: 'your host',
      secure: true, // enables FTPS/FTP with TLS
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password'
    }
  })
})
```

don't forget ask someone to implement ftp-server at your external server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-ftp